# A question of Erdős on entire functions

Tags: set-theory, analytic-functions

At the end of the following [paper](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1964-04.pdf), Erdős asked if there is a family $F$ of entire functions of size continuum such that for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $\{f(z) : f \in F\}$ has size less than continuum. He also showed how to construct such a family under CH.

Did someone solve it?

Comment: 1. What's the full citation of the Erdős paper?  2. Have you checked MathSciNet or a similar database for papers that cite this one?

Comment: Isn'it the property for which Konsevitch proved: - under CH, there exists an entire function satisfying the property, - under the negation of CH, such an entire function does not exist ?

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. What property?

Comment: A proof of this can be found in Proofs from the Book by Aigner and Ziegler. See Theorem 5, p.103.

Comment: We are probably talking about An interpolation problem associated with the continuum hypothesis, Michigan Math J 11 (1964) 9-10, MR0168482 (29 #5744).

Comment: @Malik, the location depends on the edition. In the 1st edition, it's Theorem 3, page 95.

Comment: @Ashutosh Do you know the situation under $MA+ \neg CH$ or say $PFA$?

Comment: A full proof of Erdös' result is also given as Q19, pp.335-336, in Peter Komjath, V. Totik, Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory.

Comment: Hi @MohammadGolshani, Thanks for your interest. Unfortunately, I have no idea about the truth value of this statement in models where CH fails.

Comment: @NateEldredge I did a fair bit of googling but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 11):

The following (negative answer to Erdos' question) will appear in a joint work with Shelah.

Claim: Suppose $V \models 2^{\aleph_0} = \lambda > \kappa = \aleph_1$. Let $P$ add $\kappa$ Cohen reals. Then in $V^{P}$, there is no such family.

Proof: Let $r \in {}^{\kappa}2$ be the Cohen generic sequence. Clearly $V[r] \models 2^{\aleph_0} = \lambda$. Suppose $\langle f_{\alpha} : \alpha < \lambda \rangle$ is a sequence of pairwise distinct analytic functions in $V[r]$. Choose $X \in [\lambda]^{\lambda}$, $\xi_{\star} < \kappa$ such that for each $\alpha \in X$, $f_{\alpha}$ is coded in $V[r \upharpoonright \xi_{\star}]$. Let $z_{\star} \in \mathbb{C}$ be Cohen over $V[r \upharpoonright \xi_{\star}]$. Since two distinct analytic functions only agree on a countable set, it follows that $\langle f_{\alpha}(z_{\star}) : \alpha \in X \rangle$ are pairwise distinct.

Update: Shelah and I [showed](http://www.math.huji.ac.il/~akumar/efwso.pdf) that the answer to Erdos' question is independent of ZFC + not CH so the other direction also holds.

An interesting question that remains open is: Is the following consistent: $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$ and there exists $U \in [\mathbb{C}]^{\aleph_1}$ such that for every $A \in [\mathbb{C}]^{\aleph_1}$, there is a non constant entire map that sends $A$ into $U$?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe following theorem help us to answer the question.

**Theorem**: The continuum hypothesis is true if and only if there is an
uncountable family $\mathcal{F}$ of entire analytic functions such that for each $z\in\mathbb{C}$ the set of values $\{f(z):z\in\mathbb{C}\}$ is countable.

Please see Theorem 14.4 of [Forcing for Mathematicians](https://books.google.nl/books?id=cAYkngEACAAJ&dq=forcing%20for%20mathematicians%2Bweaver&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OTeZVceeL4TEygPV4qXYCw&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA)  by Weaver for the proof

Comment: I don't see how. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Ashutosh I'm sorry, I understood wrongly. I tried to answer it, but I couldn't. I edited the answer, maybe the Theorem helps others to answer your question.